# Unable to setup OpenSSH server on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ssh, openssh

I have been spending the last 4 hours trying to get my VNC connection to work. Eventually, I realized it was because my Ubuntu remote host was unable to host SSH connections- **even though I had already installed openssh-server**.

I then tried some basic tests to verify that `sshd` was working on my machine, and found that `ssh localhost` gives a `Connection refused on port 22` error. Also, `sudo service ssh start` and `sudo start ssh` both give a `start: Unknown job: ssh` error. I tried purging and reinstalling `openssh-server`, but no luck. Why can't I receive clients?

Comment: Do you have an '/etc/init/ssh.conf' file?

Comment: @Santeador Yes.

Comment: An it doesn't even start rebooting?

Comment: Try from a shell `pgrep -l sshd`. It should answer with the PID and sshd (something like `1379 sshd`). If not, run manually `sshd` and check it again with `pgrep -l sshd` and with `ssh localhost`.

Comment: the ssh service is `sshd`, not ssh.  try `sudo service sshd start`

Comment: @RussellUhl Unfortunately, I get a `sshd: unrecognized service`.

Comment: @Hastur The `pgrep` does not print out anything, but `sshd` is not in my PATH either. I found one in my `/usr/sbin` directory, but it says `Could not load host key` about 4 times, then says `Missing privilege separation directory`.

Comment: If pgrep did not find it means that it is not running. Try `sudo service ssh start` ...

Comment: I THOUGHT it was sshd but apparently it's not.  my bad there.  sorry for the confusion.  Do `sudo service --status-all` (i know this works, i just ran it).  do you see ANYTHING ssh-related in that list?

Comment: @RussellUhl **Yes**, I see a `[ - ]  ssh`.

Comment: @JamesKo It may be this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/1367214